# CMake include 3rd party project

Tags: c++, cmake

My background is in regular makefiles, I'm trying to convert our project to a CMake setup.

I get stuck when I try to include g3log as a subproject.

I added the following lines in my CMakeLists.txt.
Note, that ../../external/g3log_src is the top level directory of the third party product.

```
target_link_libraries( myproject LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} g3log)
set(DG3_SHARED_LIB OFF)
include_directories("../../external/g3log_src/include")
add_subdirectory (../../external/g3log_src LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH/g3log)
```

However, it would not actually build g3log and so I cannot link it:
ld: library not found for -lg3log

There is a line

```
project (g3log)
```

included in the g3log CMakeLists.txt

I guess I'm missing something fundamental and easy here, but I'm lacking pointers on how to tackle the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When link with the 3d-party library, you should use **library name**, not a *project name*. In case of g3log, the library name is `g3logger`.

Also, building 3d-party project should **prepend** using it:

```
add_subdirectory (../../external/g3log_src g3log)
...
target_link_libraries( myproject LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} g3logger)
```

This is because linking should be performed with **target name**, which is known to CMake only after processing 3d-party project.

Otherwise, you just pass `-lg3logger` option to the linker, but the linker cannot find this library because it hasn't built at the moment.